# Python understanding writer.row & writer.rows

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I am a field engineer & sometimes I need to manually log some machine parameters. I have made this cli using python which I use in Android **termux**. Very handy for logging 5-6 parameters of a machine say chiller.

I wrote another version which dumps all data at once to csv file but because logging can extend to x3 hours so that method though fast is less reliable (probable data loss)

```
from tabulate import tabulate
from datetime import datetime
import csv

def _now():
    now = datetime.now()
#   datetime obj to str
    dt_string = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    return dt_string

def _deltat(a,b):
    time_fmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
#   str to datetime obj
    _init = datetime.strptime(a, time_fmt)
    _fnl = datetime.strptime(b, time_fmt)
    _delta = _fnl - _init
    return _delta.seconds

data = []
_file = input('Enter .csv file name: ')
#The last label can be 'remarks' for user to add any informative string for that data point
_count = input('Enter data labels separated by comma: ')
labels = [x.strip() for x in  _count.split(',')]
data.append(['Time'] + ['Δsec'] + labels)


#Saving data
with open(f'{_file}.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    i = 1
    #Entering data
    while True:
        a=[]
        if i==1:
                writer.writerows(data)
#               writer.writerow(data) -> "['Time', 'Δsec', 'io', 'oi', 'po']"
                a.append( _now() )
                a.append(0)
        else:
                a.append( _now() )
                delta = _deltat(data[i-1][0], a[0])
                a.append(delta)
        for x in labels:
                _a = input(f'{x}: ')
                a.append(_a)
        writer.writerow(a)
#       writer.writerows(a) -> _csv.Error: iterable expected, not int
        data.append(a)
        _exit = input(f'Data point-{i} done! Press Enter or type n to exit?: ')
        i += 1
        if _exit == 'n':
                break

#Displaying data
print( '\n', tabulate(data, headers="firstrow") )
```

I want to understand x2 lines which are commented on code & the error is also mentioned.

1] `writer.writerow(data)` this line holds a unidimensional list (label header row) but the output `"[ ... ]"` is very weird?

2] the above error is circumvented using `.writerows` but this 2nd error throws an `iterator` error? In both cases we have unidimensional list.

Further note: I used `breakpoint()` python debugging to `p data` & `p a` to display object contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically writerows requires an interable of iterables, more coloquially we can think of that as:

> a "list of rows"

or, of asking the writer:

> "write these rows (plural)"

In code this would look something like:

```py
writer.writerows(
    [
        ['Col1','Col2'],
        ['r1c1','r1c2'],
        ['r2c1','r2c2'],
    ]
)
```

to write 3 rows by 2 columns.

When your loop gets to this line, `writer.writerows(a)`, what does `a` look like?  It looks something like:

```py
['2024-02-19 10:18:27', 3, 'foo', ...]
```

1. writerows sees a list of things, and a list is iterable.

   1. So, writerows starts at the first item, `'2024-02-19 10:18:27'`, and a str is iterable.

      1. So, it writes a complete row from that, encoding each iterated char as its own field in the row:

         ```
         2,0,2,4,-,0,2,-,1,9, ,1,0,:,1,8,:,2,7
         ```
   2. Then, it goes to the second item, `3`, your int-delta, and bombs because:

      `iterable expected, not int`.

If you only intend to write one row, use writerow (no "s").

Also, I offer the following as another way to think of how to loop, and compute the delta, without trying to append and read from a growing list of data:

```py
import csv
from datetime import datetime


TIME_FMT = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"


def get_now() -> str:
    return datetime.now().strftime(TIME_FMT)


def get_delta(a: str, b: str) -> str:
    a_dt = datetime.strptime(a, TIME_FMT)
    b_dt = datetime.strptime(b, TIME_FMT)
    return str((b_dt - a_dt).seconds)


fname = input("Enter .csv file name: ")
labels_str = input("Enter data labels separated by comma: ")
labels = [x.strip() for x in labels_str.split(",")]
header = ["Time", "Δsec"] + labels

with open(fname + ".csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(header)

    now = get_now()
    last = now

    i = 0
    while True:
        print(f"{now} Enter data point for each label:")

        row = [now, get_delta(last, now)]
        for x in labels:
            v = input(f"  {x}: ").strip()
            row.append(v)
        writer.writerow(row)

        i += 1
        _continue = input(f"Data point {i} done.  Press Enter to continue, or N/n to exit: ")  # fmt: skip
        if _continue.lower().strip() == "n":
            break

        # Recompute after "continue", just before next iteration
        last = now
        now = get_now()
```

If you want to display the final result, how about reading back from the CSV once you've exited the loop and the with-open context (the file will have been flushed and closed)?